# .svn directories are being deleted when running in gwt dev mode

Tags: svn, gwt, maven

Here is my environment:

- Eclipse 3.6.1 - J2EE version
- Sonatype m2eclipse plugin for maven
- Maven 3.0.2
- Gwt 2.3.0
- Google Eclipse plugin
- gwt-maven-plugin by Mojo
- Subversion
- Subclipse plugin for svn

Problem:
My gwt app is set up so the war is built in src/main/webapp folder. I have several files in this folder I would like to be able to check into SVN, (.html, web.xml, etc). I have configured my pom file to delete the compiled javascript files, the .class files and the deploy directory. I have also excluded what I think are the correct files. This works fine when I run Maven clean or if I do a project clean or project build. However when I run in dev mode, those .svn directories get deleted. Here is a snippet of my pom:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4.1</version>
<configuration>
    <filesets>
        <fileset>
        <directory>${webappDirectory}</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>mydir/**</include>
                <include>*.class</include>
                <include>WEB-INF/deploy/**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>${webappDirectory}</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.MF</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
                <exclude>**/.svn</exclude>
            </excludes>                            
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
        </fileset>
      </filesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have searched these forums and the Net, but have only found a couple links to this problem.
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6378&q=deleting%20.svn%20directories&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/Dvumj0BAJjg

I have tried the solutions suggested but they did not work for me. I have disabled project validation and also the Google Web Toolkit Project Validator. It seems that disabling these is not a preferred method of fixing a problem.

When I look at my Maven console when hitting the run button, it appears that it is using the Maven incremental build and essentially the full maven lifecycle. I would think my configuration for the maven-clean-plugin would be sufficient, but obviously not, so I'm wondering what other plugin may need to be configured or what in my eclipse environment or run configuration needs to be changed. Here are the args in my run configuration:

```
-remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -startupUrl Synesis7cms.html -logLevel DEBUG -port 8888 -war C:\workspace\cms\src\main\webapp -codeServerPort 9997 com.synesis7.cms.Synesis7cms
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction here? I am still learning Maven, so I'm guessing it has something to do with my pom, but I have also noticed that the integration between the GWT and eclipse plugins can be problematic at times.

Thanks so much,
Mitch

Answer (score 1):

I believe the right direction is to *not* use src/main/webapps as your *war* folder: http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq.html#gwt_with_maven

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but maybe I don't understand how GWT, Maven, and Eclipse play together. I have a Dynamic Web Module facet configured, which creates a Web Resources folder that contains my src/main/webapp folder. In the project properties -> Google -> Web Application I have checked "This project has a WAR directory" and pointed it to src/main/webapp. I do not have the "launch and deploy from this directory" checked. I have been following the recommended project organization from the Mojo gwt-maven-plugin site: http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/project.html

Comment: Basically, your src/main/webapp has to remain a "sources" directory, so you don't want to run DevMode with `-war src/main/webapp` as it would generate things (nocache.js, etc.) in there. Plus, your dependencies and compiled classes are not in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib; but they are in the target/yourmodulename-version/, so that's what you want to use as your WAR directory. Eclipse should already output your compiled classes there, so reloading the server (from the DevMode view in Eclipse) should just work.

Comment: I appreciate your input, it explains some of my misunderstanding with gwt, maven, and eclipse. The way I understood the link you provided was to use the src/main/webapp as the war directory and run dev mode out of it, but you are saying only use it as the source and set my run config to use the target directory. So, do I just change my run config to use the target folder since I have configured my project based on your link and the mojo link? I am still not sure how to get the files that don't change checked into svn because I know the target and webapp folders get deleted on a build.

Comment: The important part is that in the Arguments tab of your launch config, the `-war` argument points to your target folder, and not src/main/webapp